# AWS SES: Can't send emails from any one of the new regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have the problem that i can't send emails from the new aws ses environments, [which were introduced a month ago.](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/amazon-ses-is-now-available-in-three-additional-aws-regions/)

All the old ones are working fine (e.g. us-east-1, us-west-2, eu-west-1).
But if I want to send a mail from one of the new environments, e.g. eu-central-1, I just get the error message:

`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.`

But this can't be the case, because all the old ones are working fine with the same keys.

Therefore I would really appreciate it if sb else could test the sample code with their account to check if they have the same issue. 
The new environments are eu-central-1, ap-south-1 and ap-southeast-2. [Endpoint Urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ses.html)

Sample Code:

```
var ses = require('node-ses');
var client = ses.createClient({ key: '', secret: '', amazon: 'https://email.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'});


async function sendMessage() {
    let options = {};
    options.from = "test@aol.com";
    options.to = "test2@aol.com";
    options.subject = "TestMail";
    options.message = "Test";
    console.log("Try to sendMessage");
    client.sendEmail(options, function (err, data, res) {
        console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        console.log("Data: " + data);
        console.log("res: " + res);
    });
}

sendMessage();
```

The sample code uses the [node-ses npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ses) and you just need to enter aws iam user credentials, which have ses access. 
If you want to check different regions, you have to change url in the `createClient` constructor.

**Dont worry, the sample code does not send an email!!!**

If the region is working, it should throw an error message similar to this: `Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region EU-WEST-1: test@aol.com, test2@aol.com"`

Otherwise the error will be the one described above.
I also have to mention that I am currently still in sandbox mode, so maybe the new regions are blocked for sandbox users?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you must be creating the SES credentials from the IAM console . You should instead create the credentials using the SES interface/console.

Follow this article to create smtp credentials using SES interface:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/GettingStartedGuide/GetAccessIDs.html.

Comment: I already tried that before, the smtp credentials dont work at all.
And that cant be the problem, because the credentials work and I can send emails from either one of the old ses environments, e.g. us-east-1.
Just the new ones, which were recently added, don't work.

Comment: > the credentials that you use to send email through the Amazon SES SMTP interface are unique to each AWS Region. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html

Comment: Yes, I now.
But I dont use the smtp interface, i use the ses api.
Therefore I use the iam user, which should work across regions (and does work in us-west-1, us-east-1 and eu-west-1).
Just the new environments don't work.

Comment: Ok did you obtain the SMTP credential from the IAM user credentials. You must derive the user's SMTP credentials from their AWS credentials using the algorithm provided in this section. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html

Comment: Do you still facing the issue. I'm interested to know how you fixed it